# ActiveRecord find the first record with a value AFTER a record with a certain value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, stored-procedures

I have a model, say `Model`, that has a column called `state` and the four possible states are `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`.

Is it possible (with ActiveRecord) to write a method in the `Model` class that houses a single query that finds latest occurrence of the `created_at` time of of a `B` record that is preceded by an `A` (there can be other `C` and `D` records inbetween). If there are no `A`'s in the table, it returns the oldest occurrence of `B`.

The default scope of the table is `created_at DESC`, so calling `Model.first` would be the most recent record in the table.

Currently, this is my method:

```
    class Model < ActiveRecord::Base       

      def self.getLatestBTime
         latestA = self.where("state = ?", "A").first # Record of most recent "A"
         while 1
           if !latestA.nil?
             nextB = self.where("state = ? AND created_at > ?", "B", latestA.created_at).last # Record of the first "B" after the most recent "A"
             return nextB.created_at if !nextB.nil?
           else
             break
           end
           latestA = self.where("state = ? AND created_at < ?", "A", latestA.created_at).first
         end # End while

         firstB = self.where("state = ?", "B").first
         if !firstB.nil?
           return firstB.created_at
         else
           return nil
         end
      end


    end
```

But I'm trying to find kind of an "all-in-one" style of query to ActiveRecord so I'm offloading as much work as possible to the DB rather than the application. Any suggestions?

Also, the deployment database hasn't been chosen and it can be really whatever makes the most sense (currently deploying to Heroku, so PostgresQL is what is currently used for production testing), but I'd really like to stay away from stored procedures and other methods that would take remove the layer of abstraction that ActiveRecord provides.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately you did not write what you actually want to achieve with your code. from what i understood, you are probably looking for a state machine. with some luck, everything that you need is using a gem such as https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine